# jQuery FadeOut FadeIn

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am messing with html, css and jquery, and I've run in this problem. 
I have a slideshow that gets images using fadeIn and fadeOut from a container, but when I press 'next', it's resetting the page and loads the next image somewhere at the bottom.
Can you tell me what's the problem?

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow ">
<div class="container">
<div class="slides">
<img class ="slide active-slide" src="http://gearnuke.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/GTA-5.jpg">
<img class ="slide" src="http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/gta5.jpg">
<img class ="slide" src="http://www.igta5.com/images/official-artwork-trevor-yellow-jack-inn.jpg">
<img  class="slide" src="http://cdn2.knowyourmobile.com/sites/knowyourmobilecom/files/styles/gallery_wide/public/0/67/GTAV-GTA5-Michael-Sweatshop-1280-2277432.jpg?itok=nKEHENTW">
</div>
</div>



<div class="container ">
<ul class="slider-dots">
<a href="#/" class="arrow-prev"><<</a>
    <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
<a href="#/" class="arrow-next">>></a>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var main=function(){
$('.arrow-next').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide=$('.active-slide').next();

    var currentDot=$('.active-dot');
    var nextDot=currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length==0) {nextDot=$('.dot').first(); nextSlide=$('.slide').first();}

    currentSlide.fadeOut().removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn().addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');


}); 

$('.arrow-prev').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide=currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot=$('.active-dot');
    var prevDot=currentDot.prev();

if(prevSlide.length==0) {prevDot=$('.dot').last(); prevSlide=$('.slide').last();}

    currentSlide.fadeOut().removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn().addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');

});
```

};

$(document).ready(main);

You can see it all in this
       `fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/1zLd58yo/

Comment: Please post your code, and *not* just a jsfiddle

Comment: `event.defaultPrevented` is not how you stop default behaviour. Might be after https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation instead or just return false at the end of the handler.

Comment: It has the same behaviour. I'm suspicious that somehow, the display rule in the css has something to do with it.

Comment: to avoid a reflow, your slides (even display:none) should probably be position: absolute so that all the slides are known to be at the same position

Comment: Yeah, but it messes with the container and I'd really want it just not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a fadeOut then a fadeIn.
After the fadeout, the image disappears then a new one appears. 
There is a repaint/happening after the fadeout.

Apply the following css rules to fix your issue.

On div.slides, 
  -Set a fixed width and height
  -Set position to relative

On the images, 
  - set position=absolute

Comment: And what about image spawning under the current one when the button is clicked? You think you have any idea for that?

Comment: The repaint doesn't appear, but the image is shifted right for some amount, I'd wish it would be staying inside my div. I'll modify the fiddle to display the result.

Comment: If u set position to absolute, all the images will be behind each other so there will be no spawning below.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but the images are shifted, they do not confine inside the slides div/ container.

Comment: must be something to do with the width and height of .slideshow

Comment: I've succeeded in fixing this problem, but clicking the arrows still shift my page upwards.  have to fix this now.

Comment: To fix the shift, try changing the link to a span or button.

Answer (score 0):

Set the div slides to a specific height then add put the fadeIn in a function after fadeOut, this will make sure the height doesn't grow too big. That way you can avoid setting position to absolute.

```
currentSlide.fadeOut().removeClass('active-slide', function(){
    prevSlide.fadeIn().addClass('active-slide');
});
```

First slide will completely fade out then the next one will fade in.